# How to maintain the Browser state in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to maintain the Browser state like zoom level and current content displaying etc in windows phone 7?

I want to display the same content and zoom level when the app is return from tomstoning.

Thanks,

Balaram.

Answer (score 0):

There is no zoom level property on the WebBrowser control for you to be able to persist and then restore. You can store the URL that the user has navigated to and restore that, though.

Jeff Prosise's [Real-World Tombstoning in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/02/07/real-world-tombstoning-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-part-4.aspx) should tell you pretty much everything you need to know about tombstoning.